# Is a row vector actually a number of vectors lying on one axis?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I started study Linear Algebra and i am trying to understand more visually what is a row vector so my understanding settles better. 
Is a row vector actually, a number of vectors that are all placed on one axis? 
That is, if you complement those vectors with the rest of their coordinates in the other rows, then their other coordinates are simply zero 
For example if i have this row vector:
\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3&4\\\end{bmatrix} In fact i have 4 vercors so the "real" matrix is: \begin{bmatrix}1&2&3&4\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}

so from 4D its actully 1D because all the Basis vectors are now lying on one axis.
is this make sense or I am completely wrong about that?

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be helpful to think of any $n\times m$ matrix as a linear transformation from $m$-d space to $n$-d space. So a row vector is really a $1\times 4$ matrix, that is, it is a function that takes a $4$-d vector as input and gives a $1$-d vector (a simple number) as output. In fact, you can think of a row vector as 'the operation of taking a dot product' with the corresponding column vector.